# Appending method data to ActiveRecord array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to figure out how to do this, without the messy way I've managed to do it with below.

What the below does, is returns the list of users, but adds a `user_type: { type: "ADMIN" }` to each one of the records in the Array that is returned.

`user_type` is a method on my User model, that I for specific reasons do not want to include in the DB.

```
{ explore: {
  "Popular Users": { hidden: false, position: 1, users: JSON.parse(User..select { |s| s.user_type[:type] == "ADMIN" }.to_json(methods: :user_type)) }
} }
```

This works fine, but the only way I've found to include a 'method value' on each of the Array items in the response, is to use `.to_json(methods: :user_type))`.. and then I have to JSON.Parse it again so that I can return it out on the API.

So, question is, how can I add the value from a method, to each of the records in the `.select` response?

Comment: I would say you don't need to add anything to the collection (or AR relation) - all you need is an ability to extend the serialized collection with some additional properties. This is what serializers are for...

Comment: Instead of parsing the response from `to_json` use `as_json`. `to_json` = JSON string representation of `as_json` data structure (generally a `Hash`). That being said a modern serializer might make this more maintainable in the future.